# How to connect my android studio project with svn

Tags: svn, android-studio

I have a simple android studio project want to link my project with svn so that anyone can import it and can work on it. But I don't know how to link my project with svn with new created folder. Only SVN not other version control system.

Comment: I guess that by "import it" you actually mean "export it" which in Subversion terms should be "checkout".

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA. Therefore, the steps should be the same as described in its documentation. See
[Importing a Local Directory to Subversion Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-a-local-directory-to-subversion-repository.html).

Comment: how to create a new repository on SVN(Server side).